# Why doesn't vectorization speed up these loops?

Tags: fortran, g++, vectorization, gfortran

I'm getting up to speed with vectorization, since my current PC supports it. I have an Intel i7-7600u. It has 2 cores running at 2.8/2.9 GHz and supports SSE4.1, SSE4.2 and AVX2. I'm not sure of the vector register size. I believe it is 256 bits, so will work with 4 64 bit double precision values at a time. I believe this should give a peak rate of: 
(2.8GHz)(2 core)(4 vector)(2 add/mult) = 45 GFlops.
I am using GNU Gfortran and g++.

I have a set of fortran loops I built up back in my days of working on various supercomputers. 
One loop I tested is:

```
do j=1,m
  s(:) = s(:) + a(:,j)*b(:,j)
enddo
```

The vector length is 10000, m = 200 and the nest was executed 500 times to give 2e9 operations. I ran it with the j loop unrolled 0, 1, 2, 3 and 5 times. Unrolling should reduce the number of times s is loaded and stored. It is also optimal because all the memory accesses are stride one and it has a paired add and multiply. I ran it using both array syntax as shown above and by using an inner do loop, but that seems to make little difference. With do loops and no unrolling it looks like:

```
do j=1,m
   do i=1,n
      s(i)=s(i)+a(i,j)*b(i,j)
   end do
end do
```

The build looks like:

```
gfortran -O3 -w -fimplicit-none -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec loops.f90
```

The compiler says the loops are all vectorized. The best results I have gotten is about 2.8 GFlops, which is one per cycle. If I run it with:

```
gfortran -O2 -w -fimplicit-none -fno-tree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec loops.f90
```

No vectorization is reported. It executes a little slower without unrolling, but the same with unrolling. Can someone tell me what is going on here? Do I have the characterization of my processor wrong? Why doesn't vectorization speed it up? I was expecting to get at least some improvement. I apologize if this plows old ground, but I could not find a clean example similar to this.

Comment: I often use `-march=native -O3`. The native arch may help to enable hardware acceleration.

Comment: Read https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/03/31/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this

Comment: We also need your GCC version, be sure to try the latest one.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I adding the -march option, but didn't change anything. I am running `GNU Fortran (GCC) version 5.4.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)`. @VladimirF I've read a ton of information on this subject, but had not seen that one. It's like deja vu after years of working on supercomputers.

Comment: @VladimirF the article is about use of array syntax. I ran two versions of every loop. One used array syntax as in  the posted code and one with an inner loop. In my previous experience loops are faster, but in this case it did not make any difference.

Comment: @L.Young That is the point! The article tels you to write just `A`, not `A(:)`. But yes, explicit loops are often a bit faster.

Comment: @VladimirF in this example the colon can be omitted on s, but not on a and b. The greater efficiency has more to do with optimization. Array syntax is often translated into the equivalent of one line do loops, which tends to be inefficient.

Comment: @L.Young Of course, I do understand that. Did you *really* read the article...??

Comment: Could it have something to do with Cygwin? I ran across this article - https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/04/14/is-avx-enabled

Comment: This looks pretty much like a stream triad kernel (except the scalar being also an array in this case), so the limiting factor *could* be the memory bandwidth. Thus I think it would also be interesting to know about your memory setup, i.e. how many modules on which memory channels.

Comment: By the way, Intel CPUs reduce their frequency when there are AVX instructions. This is due to the higher power consumption and the increased heat. So you can't calculate with 2.8GHz. See the linked papers for more information: https://communities.intel.com/thread/87851

Comment: @PVitt thanks. The loop is a kerrnel out of a code I wrote. It is a bit slower than a Saxpy because they are all vectors that have to be loaded. The i7-7600u is in a Lenova laptop. I have been wondering if Lenova might have AVX completely turned off for power saving or something.